# c# certificates. localMachine vs CurrentUser

Tags: c#, https, certificate

Im trying to get my mvc3 app to call a web service over https. Here is my code:

```
 var basicHttpsBinding = new BasicHttpsBinding();
            basicHttpsBinding.MaxBufferPoolSize = 104857600;
            basicHttpsBinding.MaxBufferSize = 104857600;
            basicHttpsBinding.MaxReceivedMessageSize = 104857600;
            basicHttpsBinding.Security.Mode = System.ServiceModel.BasicHttpsSecurityMode.Transport;
            basicHttpsBinding.Security.Transport.ClientCredentialType = HttpClientCredentialType.Certificate;

            var endpointAddress = new EndpointAddress("web service url.asmx");

            var cfClient = new ChannelFactory<ws_name_webreqSoap>(basicHttpsBinding, endpointAddress);


            ClientCredentials cc = cfClient.Endpoint.Behaviors.Find<ClientCredentials>();
            cc.ClientCertificate.SetCertificate(
                StoreLocation.LocalMachine,
                StoreName.My,
                X509FindType.FindByThumbprint,
                "00000000000000000000000000000000000"
                );

            cfClient.CreateChannel();

            var webServices = new ws_merit_webreqSoapClient(basicHttpsBinding, endpointAddress);
```

When i use "LocalMachine, i get the following error":

The client certificate is not provided. Specify a client certificate in ClientCredentials.

and when i use "currentUser" i get the following error:

Cannot find the X.509 certificate using the following search criteria: StoreName 'TrustedPeople', StoreLocation 'CurrentUser', FindType 'FindByThumbprint', FindValue

How can i fix the first error? What am i doing wrong?

Thanks

Comment: Are you passing the "00000000000000000000000000000000000" string to the SetCertificate method, or have you simply removed your thumbprint string from your code for pasting here?

Comment: ive just removed it for pasting here

Comment: Is it throwing the error on this line... 'cfClient.CreateChannel();'?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your code, I don't see where you are adding the ClientCredentials instance as a behavior on your factory endpoint.

After creating the ClientCredentials instance and setting its properties... do this,

```
  cfClient.Endpoint.Behaviors.Add(cc);
```

before calling, `cfClient.CreateChannel();`